# setRetainInstance(true) won't work when there is nested fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, view

In my current structure, I have a Fragment A, and under Fragment A it will add Fragment B or C. I want to use setRetainInstance(true) since my xml won't change for different orientation and it's the easiest way to go. I can't use setRetainInstance(true) inside Fragment B or C since they are nested fragments and the system won't let me do that. I can do setRetainInstance(true) in Fragment A; However, it won't work. Why doesn't it work in the parent fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested support fragments **are** retained as of [this fix in Support Library 24.0.0](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197271) or on Android N framework fragments.